# Why doesn't my OOT block appear in the GNU Radio Companion block list?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

**Context:**

I'm getting into custom block development with GNU Radio. I've implemented a simple block called `trivial_adder_ii` with 1 `int` input and 1 `int` output which produces values simply multiplied by 2. The point of the exercise is to get a sense of code structure, tools and procedures.

I've used `gr_modtool` to create the module and the block, have updated the `work` method in `trivial_adder_ii_impl.cc` to produce the expected output and implemented a python unit test which passes. So far, so good.

**The problem:**

I can't get my new block to show up in the GRC block list. This is what I do (as per various tutorials):

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I've also created this conf. file with the following content, again, as described e.g. [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-08/msg00194.html) and under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762906/where-is-my-oot-block-in-gnuradio-get-installed):

```
$ cat ~/.gnuradio/config.conf 
[grc]
local_block_path=/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
```

I can see the XML file seemingly properly deployed:

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/testmodule_trivial_adder_ii.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<block>
  <name>trivial_adder_ii</name>
  <key>testmodule_trivial_adder_ii</key>
  <category>testmodule</category>
  <import>import testmodule</import>
  <make>testmodule.trivial_adder_ii()</make>
  <sink>
    <name>in</name>
    <type>int</type>
  </sink>

  <source>
    <name>out</name>
    <type>int</type>
  </source>
</block>
```

However, my module doesn't show up in GRC, regardless of triggering "reload blocks" or restarting GRC after deploying the module XML. What am I doing wrong?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04.1, x86_64, GNU Radio Companion 3.7.2.1.

Comment: Update: added `local_blocks_path = /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks` under the `[grc]` section of `/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/grc.conf`, refreshed GRC, no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably listed in the *(no module specified)* category. To have it appear under *TestModule*, for example, change the XML block definition to:

```
<category>[TestModule]</category>
```

Update: correct answer provided in my comment below: it's "blocks" (plural), not "block".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've already specified the category: `<category>testmodule</category>`. I've just updated it to `[testmodule]`, in line with existing module names, but other than that, it looks fine to me. Any other ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, it's `local_blocks_path`, i.e., plural. Are there any other modules in the same path?I tested the XML file and it works for me. The block shows up under "(no module specificed)/testmodule/trivial_adder_ii".

Comment: I'm just going to go and throw myself off of the city walls...thanks, bastibl.  Lovely that GRC didn't bring this up in any way when I ran it from the console...

Comment: That said, I'm still puzzled by the fact that editing `/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/grc.conf` had no effect, but it's now an academic question, as opposed to a practical one.